# Nslookup works but anything else fails

Tags: networking, internet, configuration, dns, connection

I started from a fresh ubuntu 14 server and installed lamp stack.

At some point i decided to install dnsmasq, then i changed my mind and apt purge'd it.

The next reboot after i did that, i am faced with all sorts of networking related problems which i think are because of the purge :|

For instance, immediately after every reboot, i can't nslookup anything.
I'll have to run dhclient which sets up nameservers correctly but still hangs with no errors. After Ctrl + C i try nslookup again and now it works fine.

However, pinging or wget or apt-get refuse to connect to anything, even though they do the ip lookup correctly.

I'm not sure where/how to start debugging this. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

So, i have to admit, i don't understand why this fixes the problem but if i move out

```
/etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d/sendmail
/etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d/postfix
```

to let's say my home directory, and reboot, then everything is fine.

I would still like to have an explanation of why that happened and what these 2 files do in particular.